# Steepest descent with quadratic form converges in 1 iteration

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, numerical-methods, quadratic-forms

Well I'm stuck on an exercise given:

> The steepest descent method is applied to the quadratic form
>
> $$Q(\mathbf{x}) = \tfrac{1}{2}\mathbf{x}^TA\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{b}^T\mathbf{x} + c$$
> where $A$, $\mathbf{b}$ and $c$, are matrix, vector and scalar constants. Under what condition on the matrix $A$ does the steepest descent method converge to the exact minimum in 1 iteration, from any initial condition $x_0$? [Hint: If the initial search line $\mathbf{x}_0 + \alpha \mathbf{d}_0$ includes the exact minimum of $Q(\mathbf{x})$, then the method will converge in 1 iteration.]

More specifically, some conditions about the matrix $A$ are asked, seeing this is a multiple choice question, the options:

> 1. $A$ is a multiple of the identity matrix
> 2. $A$ is diagonal
> 3. $A$ is symmetric
> 4. $A$ is positive definite
> 5. $A$ has only positive eigenvalues
> 6. $A$ is equal to $\mathbf{b}\mathbf{b}^T$
> 7. It never converges in 1 iteration
> 8. It always converges in 1 iteration

---

Now following the "hint", the exact solution is given by solving $Q'(\mathbf{x}) = 0$:
$$A\mathbf{\tilde{x}} - \mathbf{b} = 0$$
$$\mathbf{\tilde{x}} = A^{-1} \mathbf{b}$$

From the definition of the steepest descent method ($x_{n+1} = x_n - \alpha f'(x_n)$):

$$\mathbf{x}_1 = \mathbf{x}_0 + \alpha (A\mathbf{x}_0-\mathbf{b})$$

Now $\mathbf{x}_1 = \mathbf{\tilde{x}}$ has to be solved, or written out:

$$\mathbf{x}_0 + \alpha (A\mathbf{x}_0-\mathbf{b}) = A^{-1} \mathbf{b} \qquad \forall\ \mathbf{x}_0,\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$$

Now I'm stuck, what can be said about $A$? Geometrically it feels like solution should be easy to be found, an example is a "cone like surface".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have existence of a minimizer, $A$ must be positive semi-definite and the equation $Ax=b$ must be solvable.

Assume the steepest descent converges in one step,  i.e. $x_1$ is the solution. Then
$$
0=Ax_1-b=A(x_0 - \alpha(Ax_0-b))-b = (I-\alpha A)(Ax_0-b)
$$ 
hence $Ax_0-b$ has to be an eigenvector if $A$ (or $Ax_0-b=0$).
The reverse direction is also true, you need that $Ax_0-b$ is an eigenvector to a positive eigenvalue of $A$.

Can you find now,
which of the given choices imply one-step convergence?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** two conditions are important; first, the function $Q(\mathbf{x})$ must actually have a minimum, and the inverse of the matrix $\mathbf{A}$ must exist.

Comment: Invertibility of $A$ is not necessary for existence of minimizers of $Q$.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm really stuck here, and I don't see how this would solve it? I'm taking for granted teh minimum exists (from the way the question is asked). - As well as that A is invertible.

Comment: @daw In the question "the exact minimum" is mentioned; for a unique solution to exist, matrix $A$ must be non-singular.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked 'exact' here, and wrote a separate answer that does not rely on the uniqueness of the minimizer.

Comment: OK, thanks for clearing that up.